# Python3 telnetlib ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused error

Tags: python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

```
from random_open_port import random_port
import telnetlib

HOST = 'localhost' # Accepting clients from any IP addresses
PORT = random_port()


tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
```

It returns the error Connection Refused

Comment: Are you trying to run this as the server or the client?

Comment: Im trying to run this as the server

Comment: The telnetlib documentation says "Telnet represents a connection to a Telnet server." so it's acting as a client connecting to a server it's not acting as a telnet server

Comment: But i just want it so i can run the telnet 192.168.xxx.xxx and then port xxxx and then have like a chat app or like a login system

Comment: Then you need to find another module or look at sockets module